# Has this line judge made an obvious mistake?

Tags: officiating, badminton

Watching the recent Uber cup, I noticed that the line judge on the right is extending his arm (the sign for `In`), although the shuttle was out by quite a bit. Luckily, the line judge at the top is correctly showing that the shuttle was out by extending both arms to the sides.

[image: Two line judges showing different signs]

Has the judge made an obvious mistake, or is something else going on here?

Comment: I note that you were probably downvoted for the tone of the question. Personally, I don't find this question outside of what is respectful discourse, but just a heads-up that other users, particularly those from collectivist/authoritarian cultures may. I have upvoted to cancel out the downvote.

Comment: @studro Thanks for the pointer. I was assuming many users would be searching for `badminton line judge blind` or `badminton line judge incompetent`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Badminton line judges only judge their line.

If the shuttle comes anywhere near their line, they either signal *In*, *Out*, or *Unsighted*, but only relative to their line.

The umpire will look at both line judges; if any of the two signals *Out*, the shuttle is regarded out. Line judges can skip the signal if the decision is obvious, i.e. the shuttle landed and rested more than roughly a meter inside.

At lower-level tournaments with less line judges per court, line judges may be assigned to multiple lines, for example back line, one half of a side line, and doubles service line. In this case, the line judge indicates the composite result.

Comment: Exactly what I would have expected. Your line is yours; anything else is not. If it lands three metres clear of end but an inch inside sideline, that's "in" so far as the sideline judge is concerned.

Comment: @Nij Then luckily your intuition maches the ruleset in this case. I've heard this question (usually phrased as a statement) many times, and I can even remember thinking it myself when I watched my very first high-level Badminton match.

Comment: My intuition with rules has been well-honed, given the detail of technicality that some rulsets apply! Of course though, one should always refer to an authoritative source - and repeat that reference often, just in case it's changed.